# How to change .htaccess file to redirect to www, not http?

Tags: .htaccess

Below is the code in my .htaccess file. How do I change it to redirect visitors to `https://www` and not `http://`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after the `RewriteEngine On` directive, place the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This will handle both the `http` to `https` and `non-www` to `www` redirection. Note that external redirections should generally come *before* internal rewrites (which is what you currently have).